# Set .keyup() in a div

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I developing a system on `ASP.NET WebForm`. As it doesn't support multiple forms, I'm using these codes which is showing as 2 forms in interface, getting values by `id` and submitting values by `ajax`. But here I want to set 2 separate `.keyup()` functions for 2 virtual forms. Is it possible to do that? If yes, then how?

```
<!--First form-->
<div class="x_content form-horizontal form-label-left" id="info">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Full Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="name" placeholder="Enter full name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Contact</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="contact" placeholder="Enter contact">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="verifyInfo()">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!--Second form-->
<div class="x_content form-horizontal form-label-left" id="pass">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Old Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="password" class="required form-control" id="oldpassword" placeholder="Type old password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">New Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="password" class="required form-control" id="newpassword" placeholder="Type new password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Re-Type Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <input type="password" class="required form-control" id="repassword" placeholder="Re-type new password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="verifyPass()">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Short answer: yes/probably. Long answer: Please show your code so we have a context for this :)

Comment: I've given my code? what else to provide?

Comment: You've given _part_ of the code... where's the JavaScript?

Comment: use something like this: `$("#info :input).keyup( function(){...})`

Comment: You've given your *HTML* and none of your *code* (aside from some tantalising inline calls to functions). Please provide your *code* too :)

Comment: Thanx to fnostro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found 2 answers for this question. 1 from a comment by  `fnostro`,

```
$("#info :input").keyup( function(){...})
```

Another one is adding 2 different classes with every `:input` of 2 different forms and this function.

```
$('.classname').keyup(function(){
    //
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give [jQuery Hotkeys](http://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) a shot. It's pretty easy to use and can handle your keyup events.

To bind Ctrl+m to a couple of functions [f1 and f2], for example:

```
$('#form1').on('keyup', null, 'ctrl+m', f1);
$('#form2').on('keyup', null, 'ctrl+m', f2);
```

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Comment: Updated to use the 'on' syntax based on feedback from @ZakariaAcharki